# Calling a function of another contract is not working properly?

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a problem like this. I am very new to solidity stuff. I have created two contracts and I have called a one contract function inside another contract. Here I am providing my contracts.

This is my main contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract TrafficFine{
    struct Officer {
        string firstName ;
        string lastName;
        address account;
    }

    address public manager;
    uint public numberOfOffiers;


    mapping(address=>Officer) public officers;

    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender == manager);      
        _;
    }

    constructor () public{
        manager = msg.sender;
    }



    function addOfficer(
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        address officer) public  restricted{

        require(officer!=officers[officer].account);

        Officer  memory newOfficer = Officer({
            firstName:firstName,
            lastName:lastName,
            account:officer
        });

        officers[officer] = newOfficer;
        numberOfOffiers++;
    }



    function getofficer(address officer) public view returns(address){
        address officer1= officers[officer].account;
        return officer1;
    }


}
```

This is my second contract.

```
contract DriverProfile{
    address watch_adrs=0x8c1eD7e19abAa9f23c476dA86Dc1577F1Ef401f5;

     function doFine(uint offenceID,string location,address officer) public{
         TrafficFine trafficfine = TrafficFine(watch_adrs);
         require(officer==trafficfine.getOfficer(officer));
     }

}

contract TrafficFine{
    function addOfficer(string firstName,string lastName,address officer) public;
    function getOfficer(address officer) public;
}
```

When I compile the second DriverProfille contract it gives me an error like this.

[image: eror]

Can someone help me to solve this problem?. I search a lot to find a solution to this problem. But I was unable to do nothing to this problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second implementation of `TrafficFine` does not specify the return value.

Try changing:

```
function getOfficer(address officer) public;
```

to:

```
function getOfficer(address officer) public view returns (address);
```